# Switch in professional career due to personal circumstances

Tags: software-industry, management, software-development, software, software-engineering

I have worked as a SDE in many interesting places, working abroad and in well known companies in the industry, one of them being a FAANG, for around ten years.

Shortly after the pandemic started, I accepted a role in my hometown and moved back to my country, this is a SDET role for which I feel overqualified and to some degree and a switch in professional careers, there was personal circumstances involved in this move rather than actual interest for the role.

Fast forward a year and now I have been asked to build a department around this area of expertise, which is not really my main area of expertise but I am good enough at it as to consider me for this position, I brought practices and knowhow to the company that it was previously unheard of here.

I like the challenge as it is new for me, and the opportunity to make my vision of a department a reality, I haven't had direct reports before... but I am not sure if I want to focus my career on testing and management, and I am kind of demotivated that I happen to be the local expert in this area and thus no one really to learn from.

I am in two minds as what to do in the medium - long term, I realize that going back to my previous career path will involve moving out of my hometown and far from my family again as there are no such roles here, and that continuing with my current opportunity implies potentially throwing away a decade of experience and the feeling I might end up not liking it and locking myself to this kind of roles in the future. I am not concerned about job security as I feel both roles will have plenty for decades.

If you had a similar scenario before, I was wondering what helped you decide one way or the other and how it turned out.

Comment: Can you ask your current company to give you some position in software development (maybe, either for a new team or to improve some current teams) ? You've already proved to them that you have leadership skills at this company, and software development skills at FAANG. Maybe, they will listen to you. But, if they don't want you to work in development, can you work in SDET as the **day job**, and **at night or on the weekend**, learn and start some software development business on your own such as mobile app development to challenge yourself technically ?

Comment: Could you edit to expand the SDE and SDET acronyms?

Comment: @AdamBurke,   SDE = Software Development Engineer.  SDET = Software Development Engineer in TEST.

Comment: Could you edit the question itself to reflect that please?

Comment: I see the question has been closed for being too specific. I think there is an interesting general question, if still a somewhat software-centric one, hiding here - "can you build a technically interesting career as a software engineer after a period focusing on testing and being a test manager?" You may try another question on those lines - or people may want to kick you onto the Software Engineering SE.

Answer (score 2):

I find it very satisfying to build something from scratch that stands the test of time and expansion. I have been the first to do several things in my country. Not the best, just the only local. Much more so than doing an excellent job fulfilling part of someone elses plan. And it can build on itself as you gain experience and knowledge in how to accomplish this successfully.

In terms of moving away from family, it's not really something I would contemplate without exceptional reason since I had children. But if you mean siblings and parents then it's normal enough to go wherever your career is moving you forwards.

These are just my personal views.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explore a suitable role in a larger city in your own country? Then you can be with family for some more time.

Hybrid working can lead to a good chunk of time for work from home.

Answer (score 0):

I can see there are multiple thoughts going into your mind and I totally agree on that according to the situation those are obvious thoughts.

**You may think as per below :**

1. Do I want to build career where I am not that much interested?
2. Should I go out of town, stay away from family but do the work where I am interested and have more potential, growth and opportunities ?

Choosing career over family , I know it's not that easy. But still you have to decide.

How about going away from family for short time, Get your favorite job and then bring family with you into the same town where you are doing job?